# Google now cards not being created on Live

Tags: google-now

When I send email, using http://gmail-actions.appspot.com/ cards are being created, however on production using amazon ses email service, cards are not being created, However I can see all tags need for creating tag in the email body.

Please suggest!! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

@ashish If you're using Gmail Schemas in your production environment (xxx@yourcompany.com), you will have to register and be whitelisted for the feature. Your email will have to go through their quality checks and you will also have to send a sample email with the markup included.

You can find the guidelines to register at the link below.

https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/registering-with-google